# find_all_by issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have rails application, which deals with some google map related stuff.the problem is , i have a table which contains latitude  & longitude columns. the column types are "float". for some occasions i need to generate the query by the following:

clients.find_all_by_lat_and_lng(latvalue,lngvalue).

I gave the correct & existing lat & lng values to fetch the database value. but i can get only Empty.

I tried with difference dynamic finders like find_by_lat,find_by_lng i get only empty values from the query ...but data are exits in the table.

I guess the Float column type is the culprit here, i don't how to overcome this and get the values. Can one suggest me on this.

NOTE : if i work with  same query in windows i get the values. my box is ubuntu here i can't get the values

Answer (score 0):

```
clients.find(:all, :conditions => ["lat = ? and lng = ?",latvalue, lngvalue])
```

try this your model name is "clients" ???
or Client

Comment: No Luck, my model name is Client only. The client model has the hasmany association with Map model.so when get the map object. i tried with mapobject.clients..find(:all, :conditions => ["lat = ? and lng = ?",latvalue, lngvalue])
.... But no luck

Comment: map.clients.find(:all, :conditions => ["lat = ? and lng = ?",13.0481,80.2214])  ------------> fails

Client.find(:all,:conditions =>["lat=? and lng = ?",13.0481,80.22114]) -------------- Fails ... its returns empty